# Confusion with babel polyfills

Tags: javascript

I was learning how babel.js works and faced a bit of confusion on how babel polyfills work, that is, for example, if we add promise polyfill to babel then does that polyfill enables babel to actually convert promise into older version thanks to the polyfill added. I just cannot get how babel polyfills work

Comment: most polyfills are implementations of features that don't exist on old browsers. So for example IE does not implement `Promise`. The polyfill provides an implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Polyfill will override native function. Such as `promise-polyfill` will override `window.Promise`. So you can use `promise = new Promise` in IE

Comment: The polyfill does not override `window.Promise`. It provides an implementation of `window.Promise`. If `Promise` already exists on `window` the polyfill will not override it.